# Looking for a free SQL editor to connect from Mac to Netezza (PureData System for Analytics)

Tags: sql, editor, netezza

I'm looking for a free SQL editor to connect directly to Netezza (now called PureData System for Analytics) via my MacBook Pro. I do have a JDBC Netezza (.jar) driver

Answer (score 3):

You can go through following links to download and install "Squirrel" tool which is free and supports all platforms -

```
1) http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/#installation 
2) http://techdb.wordpress.com/2010/09/30/part-1-install-configure-sql-client-for-netezza-in-3-minutes/
```

Hope this will help.